# Magento 1.9 Shipping Method is not visible on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, delivery-date

I am having an **online ecommerce store**. I had used **flat rate** for all the **products** with **same delivery charges**. `When I add the product on my cart`, then my cart only shows main price of the product but `not showing the Delivery charges`. I had `cleared all the caches & fixed indexes`, but still facing this issue. **Sort Order is "1"**. I had attached an screenshot of frontend & backend for better understanding. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shipping is calculated when you put in the shipping address (it doesn't matter if it's fixed rate).

Also your current method is not Flat rate, it's Table rate.

To this display shipping without having to click estimate you can try this nice module https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping

Comment: Yeah, I changed it now, is it possible to display shipping rate below Main price without calculating it

Comment: Yes you can use this module https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping